# Openmp slower than serial in Android

Tags: android, openmp

I try using OpenMP to parallel Deblocking filter of OpenHEVC.
But, It is more slower than serial to using openMP. even, I tried to blank code in for loop.
However it took four time as long than serial. I don't know why it happened.

Serial code

```
for (y = y0; y < y_end; y += 8) {       
    for (x = x0 ? x0 : 8; x < x_end; x += 8) {
        const int bs0 = s->vertical_bs[(x >> 3) + (y       >> 2) * s->bs_width];
        const int bs1 = s->vertical_bs[(x >> 3) + ((y + 4) >> 2) * s->bs_width];

        int c_tc[2], beta[2], tc[2];
        uint8_t no_p[2] = { 0 };
        uint8_t no_q[2] = { 0 };


        if (bs0 || bs1) {
            const int qp0 = (get_qPy(s, x - 1, y)     + get_qPy(s, x, y)     + 1) >> 1;
            const int qp1 = (get_qPy(s, x - 1, y + 4) + get_qPy(s, x, y + 4) + 1) >> 1;

            beta[0] = betatable[av_clip(qp0 + (beta_offset >> 1 << 1), 0, MAX_QP)];
            beta[1] = betatable[av_clip(qp1 + (beta_offset >> 1 << 1), 0, MAX_QP)];
            tc[0]   = bs0 ? TC_CALC(qp0, bs0) : 0;
            tc[1]   = bs1 ? TC_CALC(qp1, bs1) : 0;
            src     = &s->frame->data[LUMA][y * s->frame->linesize[LUMA] + (x << s->sps->pixel_shift)];
            if (pcmf) {
                no_p[0] = get_pcm(s, x - 1, y);
                no_p[1] = get_pcm(s, x - 1, y + 4);
                no_q[0] = get_pcm(s, x, y);
                no_q[1] = get_pcm(s, x, y + 4);

                omp_set_lock(&writelock);
                s->hevcdsp.hevc_v_loop_filter_luma_c(src,
                    s->frame->linesize[LUMA],
                    beta, tc, no_p, no_q);
                omp_unset_lock(&writelock);
            } else{
                omp_set_lock(&writelock);
                s->hevcdsp.hevc_v_loop_filter_luma(src,
                    s->frame->linesize[LUMA],
                    beta, tc, no_p, no_q);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Openmp code

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel shared(s) private(src)
{
    #pragma omp for
for (y = y0; y < y_end; y += 8) {       
    for (x = x0 ? x0 : 8; x < x_end; x += 8) {
        const int bs0 = s->vertical_bs[(x >> 3) + (y       >> 2) * s->bs_width];
        const int bs1 = s->vertical_bs[(x >> 3) + ((y + 4) >> 2) * s->bs_width];

        int c_tc[2], beta[2], tc[2];
        uint8_t no_p[2] = { 0 };
        uint8_t no_q[2] = { 0 };


        if (bs0 || bs1) {
            const int qp0 = (get_qPy(s, x - 1, y)     + get_qPy(s, x, y)     + 1) >> 1;
            const int qp1 = (get_qPy(s, x - 1, y + 4) + get_qPy(s, x, y + 4) + 1) >> 1;

            beta[0] = betatable[av_clip(qp0 + (beta_offset >> 1 << 1), 0, MAX_QP)];
            beta[1] = betatable[av_clip(qp1 + (beta_offset >> 1 << 1), 0, MAX_QP)];
            tc[0]   = bs0 ? TC_CALC(qp0, bs0) : 0;
            tc[1]   = bs1 ? TC_CALC(qp1, bs1) : 0;
            src     = &s->frame->data[LUMA][y * s->frame->linesize[LUMA] + (x << s->sps->pixel_shift)];
            if (pcmf) {
                no_p[0] = get_pcm(s, x - 1, y);
                no_p[1] = get_pcm(s, x - 1, y + 4);
                no_q[0] = get_pcm(s, x, y);
                no_q[1] = get_pcm(s, x, y + 4);

                s->hevcdsp.hevc_v_loop_filter_luma_c(src,
                    s->frame->linesize[LUMA],
                    beta, tc, no_p, no_q);
            } else{                 
                s->hevcdsp.hevc_v_loop_filter_luma(src,
                    s->frame->linesize[LUMA],
                    beta, tc, no_p, no_q);

            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Time(longest)

Serial : 1004ns

openMP : 4150ns

Comment: Are you serious ?  *nanoseconds* ?  Perhaps more to the point, when someone reports a parallel timing on `P` processors that is, approximately, `P` times the time on 1 processor I immediately think that someone has counted CPU times not wall clock times.  You may not have made that mistake  but do always use `omp_get_wtime` for timing OpenMP programs, and an equivalent wall clock routine in your serial code.  Or, just give your OpenMP code 1 thread to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A blank loop **will** take longer in parallel than in series. You don't have nearly enough work inside the loop for it to be beneficial to you. There overhead required to spawn and close the threads is taking up most of that time.

Try putting a really heavy work load in there and see what happens! For example, I use OpenMP in Fortran code with loops that take 5 minutes per.

You could even put a 5 second sleep in just to test that they're actually running in parallel.